# Finding difference between consecutive numbers in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
A=[1,2,3,3,0]
```

and if I want to calculate difference between consecutive numbers in an array. I could do it in Matlab with using built-in function (`diff`)

`B=diff(A)` returns

```
B = [1,1,0,-3]
```

I would like to know there is any similar built-in function in javascript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no such built-in function, but writing one is simple:

```
function diff(ary) {
    var newA = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < ary.length; i++)  newA.push(ary[i] - ary[i - 1])
    return newA;
}
var A = [1, 2, 3, 3, 0];
console.log(diff(A)) // [1, 1, 0, -3]
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ewbmrjyr/1/

Comment: Thanks j08691, it works. I had thought that there might be a in-built method, then i should not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 26):

If you prefer functional programming, here's a solution using `map`:

```
function diff(A) {
  return A.slice(1).map(function(n, i) { return n - A[i]; });
}
```

A little explanation: `slice(1)` gets all but the first element. `map` returns a new value for each of those, and the value returned is the difference between the element and the corresponding element in A, (the un-`slice`d array), so `A[i]` is the element before `[i]` in the slice.

Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ewbmrjyr/2/

Comment: The code can be further simplified by using [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: `const diff = (A) => { return A.slice(1).map( (item,index) => { return item - A[index] } )}`

Answer (score 3):

The code can by simplified by using [Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var visitsArr = [38,29,18,29,28,18,24];

var diffs = visitsArr.slice(1).map((x,i)=> x-visitsArr[i]);

diffs.forEach((x,i) => console.log(
   `Visits from day ${i+1} to day ${i+2} increased by ${x}`
));
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [1,2,3,3,0] ;
function diff (arr){
    diffArr=[];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
        diffArr.push(arr[i+1]-arr[i]);

    }
    return diffArr;
}
alert(diff(a)); //[1,1,0,-3]
```

Comment: How is this fundamentally different from my answer? Seems like the same logic.